# Does the discount from Mindsplice Apparatus apply to flashback costs?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I target a [Time Warp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Time%20Warp) with [Snapcaster Mage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Snapcaster%20Mage) and there is a [Mindsplice Apparatus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mindsplice%20Apparatus) with 3 oil counters in play on my side,  can I cast Time Warp for {U}{U}?

Comment: The total cost to cast a spell = mana cost or alternative cost + additional costs and cost increases - cost reductions. Flashback is just an alternative cost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Flashback is just an alternative cost (CR 702.34a):

> Casting a spell using its flashback ability follows the rules for paying
> alternative costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2f–h.

and 601.2f explicitly allows reductions to apply to alternative costs:

> The total cost is the mana cost or alternative cost (as determined in rule 601.2b), plus all additional costs and cost increases, and minus all cost reductions.

(Rule references to the [2023-02-03 Comprehensive Rules](https://media.wizards.com/2023/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020230203.pdf))

Comment: As a somewhat interesting addendum, because of how casting costs work, cost reductions are not optional unless the ability providing them says they are, so not only could Time Warp be cast for {U}{U} in the OP's example, it _has_ to be cast for {U}{U} if being cast via flashback in that case. This usually does not matter, though there are edge cases where it has nasty implications (for example, if an opponent has [Lavinia, Azorius Renegade](https://scryfall.com/card/rna/189/lavinia-azorius-renegade) in play and your cost reductions reduce the cost to zero, then you functionally can’t cast it).